# Double click in Visual Studio 08 forms designer adds listener. Please make it stop

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio, winforms

I'm using Visual Studio 08 Designer for a Windows Forms application.  When I accidentally double click on a control it automatically switches to the code and adds a listener.  How do I stop this irritating behavior?  Nuclear Weapons?  Fire?  Both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a feature in Visual Studio and can not be turned off, however annoying it can be, it is also very useful to aid even further rapid application development.